# .inc file in Xcode

Tags: c++, import, xcode5

We're using a C/C++ library into our Xcode project, and into this library, some .cpp files included a .inc file, but Xcode seems to not recognize this kind of file.

```
"File.inc file not found"
```

But the file appears in the Project Navigator. Has anybody already faced this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Paste the **whole** error message, and note ahead of time, the preprocessor does not understand wild-card matches. You cannot `#include "*.inc"` and expect it to include all `.inc` files. That's now how the preprocessor works. One *explicit* file name at a time *only*, findable in your configured include path(s).

Comment: I have edited my question. Of course, I didn't want to include multiple file at the same time. The * was there to say that it can be any .inc file

Comment: You probably need to set the *Header Search Path* for the target in Xcode project settings.

Comment: @trojanfoe It was that ! :) One last question : do I need to specify the exact path of my .inc file, or can I specify a more general path but mark it as recursive ? I never know what to put

Comment: Yeah just use `$(SRCROOT)` to get a relative path.